# HTML Publisher plugin not showing reports for previous builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using HTML publisher plugin to report a html file from Surefire reports generated in `/target/**` folder, but when I click on HTML report on the project page it redirects me to only previous build and not the ones built before that.

My use case is that there are 3 stages in my test suite and I want to publish a report for each stage separately or provide a link to it. If not HTML publisher, which other plugin would you suggest for my use case?